# Grails stops at "Configuring classpath" even at a helloworld project

Tags: grails, classpath

I want to learn Grails, so I started with a Hello-World Projekt.
I tried everything in the cmd.exe and in STS. I have Windows7.

First i wrote `grails create-app helloworld` command

Then i swaped in the new helloworld\ directory and wrote `grails run-app`

But the command-line doesn't go furthen then `Configuring classpath`

I watched in other forums but nothing helped. 
I am sitting in a companys-internet. Does this cause the fault ?

Fault if log level is set on verbose (only the last few lines - before were about 500 other lines)

| Error Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy   for more information):

- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:7.0.42
- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-log4j:7.0.42
- org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler:ecj:3.7.2
- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-catalina-ant:7.0.42
- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-juli:7.0.42
- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper:7.0.42

Edit: I use Grails 2.2.4 and heres my BuildConfig.groovy:

```
grails.servlet.version = "2.5" // Change depending on target container compliance (2.5 or 3.0)
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.target.level = 1.6
grails.project.source.level = 1.6
//grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}-${appVersion}.war"

// uncomment (and adjust settings) to fork the JVM to isolate classpaths
//grails.project.fork = [
//   run: [maxMemory:1024, minMemory:64, debug:false, maxPerm:256]
//]

grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        // specify dependency exclusions here; for example, uncomment this to disable ehcache:
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }
    log "error" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    checksums true // Whether to verify checksums on resolve
    legacyResolve false // whether to do a secondary resolve on plugin installation, not advised and here for backwards compatibility

    repositories {
        inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        grailsCentral()

        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()

        // uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable remote dependency resolution from public Maven repositories
        //mavenRepo "http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
    }

    dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.

        // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.22'
    }

    plugins {
        runtime ":hibernate:$grailsVersion"
        runtime ":jquery:1.8.3"
        runtime ":resources:1.2"

        // Uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable additional resources capabilities
        //runtime ":zipped-resources:1.0"
        //runtime ":cached-resources:1.0"
        //runtime ":yui-minify-resources:0.1.5"

        build ":tomcat:$grailsVersion"

        runtime ":database-migration:1.3.2"

        compile ':cache:1.0.1'
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please post your BuildConfig.groovy code, mainly the code that defines your plugins. Also which version of Grails are you using?

Comment: I didnt change anything after the create-app command. So thats the BuildConfig.groovy how Grails created it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Be sure you are not behind a proxy.
Check on the command line grails list-plugins.

If this call fails: add and set the proxy and check the correct entries in the ProxySettings.groovy.

May this helps.

Comment: I added and set the proxy and checked the ProxySettings.groovy
But there I only can find the following:
`client=['http.proxyHost':true, 'http.proxyPort':true, 'http.proxyUser':'', 'http.proxyPassword':'', 'http.nonProxyHosts':'']
currentProxy='client'`

Comment: Can you spot the problem? Replace 'true' with your real values. I think it is a bug. The same happens to my proxySetting. After fixing it everything works fine.

Comment: Ok that was the problem. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Please check internet and plugin download links are accessible or not..

Comment: From the console I have not the chance to get into the internet. I tried to install a plugin from the harddrive and it worked.

I tried to uninstall the tomcat plugin with `grails uninstall-plugin tomcat`
and i got `Warning No plugin [tomcat] installed, cannot uninstall`

But I thought that tomcat comes with every grails-installation. Where can i downlaod it to install it manually from the harddrive ?

Answer (score 0):

> I am sitting in a companys-internet

I faced the same problems with my company's proxy server.

On a Windows machine in grails-version_number\bin\ there is a startGrails.bat. Here the settings for your proxy server could be set via JAVA_OPTS (towards the bottom of the file). But it would **not** be a good to do so, because when you upgrade Grails a year or so from now your customs settings will be lost. And you'll be scratching your head about why Grails no longer works and/or you cannot remember the syntax for setting the proxy server info.

So, in the same bin\ directory make a new file called setenv.bat. In that add

```
@rem  Java proxy properties for connecting to proxy server 
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dhttp.proxySet=true -Dhttp.proxyHost="proxyServerName" -Dhttp.proxyPort="0123" -Dhttp.username="userName" -Dhttp.password="userPassWord"
```

I would remove the helloworld directory you just created and then again run

```
grails create-app helloworld
```