# Error creating a new Grails Project - GGTS/STS/Eclipse with GGTS Plugin

Tags: grails

Installed Java and Grails, set the GRAILS_HOME, JAVA_HOME and Path variables. Installed GGTS and when tried to create a new Grails project I get the following error.

```
The command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin\javaw.exe (Mar 24, 2014, 1:59:29 PM)' was terminated because it didn't produce new output for some time.

See details for the output produced so far.

If you think the command simply needed more time, you can increase the time limit in the Grails preferences page.

See menu Windows >> Preferences >> Grails >> Launch
Command: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin\javaw.exe (Mar 24, 2014, 1:59:29 PM)
---- System.out ----
| Loading Grails 2.2.4
| Configuring classpath
---- System.err ----

Terminating process: Timeout: no new output for 180000 milliseconds
------System.out:-----------
 | Loading Grails 2.2.4
| Configuring classpath
------System.err:-----------

Terminating process: Timeout: no new output for 180000 milliseconds
```

Tried the same using Eclipse + GGTS plugin and still have the same issue.
Creating  anew project from command line have no issues. Created a new Grails project from command line and then imported the project into workspace and when tried to create a new controller, the same error thrown. Not sure if anyone else has the same issue.

Is GGTS mature enough? Is there an alternative?

OK, Now I close my IDE and trying from command line.
I have set my proxy settings manually as the 'set proxy' command does not update the ProxySettings file.
From command line I am able to create a new project, and when I try to compile I get this...

```
| Error Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Failed to read artifact descriptor
 for org.grails:grails-docs:jar:2.3.7 (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
| Error Required Grails build dependencies were not found. 
This is normally due to internet connectivity issues (such as a misconfigured proxy)
 or missing repositories in grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy. Please verify your
 configuration to continue. 
|
```

Comment: I haven't found any problm with ggts. I followed this http://grails.asia/grails-tutorial-for-beginners-setup-your-windows-development-environment/

Comment: 1. I see your JDK path has spaces in it, on windows that created a lot of issues for me. Make sure your JDK + GRAILS is installed in a path with no spaces. E.g. in your case it can be C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_51. For reference see my prior post


http://stackoverflow.com/a/20048435/1811107


2. I have been using GGTS for a while now and it seems stable - my personal preference is to refresh the entire environment once in 3 months.

Comment: Yes, I have been following the same (http://grails.asia/grails-tutorial-for-beginners-setup-your-windows-development-environment/) and I don't think the space in the JDK path is any issue, I can create a new project from command line using grails commands. The issue is while using the IDE, it creates the project skeleton but timesout afterwards throwing the above error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I once encountered something similar to your problem and by the grace, I connected to the internet and realisation came to mind.

Please see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20237925/grails-stops-at-configuring-classpath-even-at-a-helloworld-project) am sure it will be of aid.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
Yes, I fixed my proxy settings manually as the set proxy command is not actually updating the proxy settings file. See my edit on he original post.

Comment: The issue was the proxy, missing double quotes on windows. I had to edit the proxy settings manually though.
Thanks for your help!