# Grails : Maven Issues

Tags: maven, grails

I am trying to create a new Grails project using the Maven archetype

```
        <groupId>org.grails</groupId>
        <artifactId>grails-maven-archetype</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.7</version>
```

After the project is created I see a bunch of errors on the pom

```
Project build error: Unresolveable build extension: 
Plugin org.grails:grails-maven-plugin:2.3.7 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: 
Could not find artifact com.sun:tools:jar:1.6 at specified path C:\Program Files\Java\jre7/../lib/tools.jar
```

Why is it looking for com.sun:tools:jar:**1.6** ?

```
Project build error: Unknown packaging: grails-app
```

Why does it complain on the packaging type - **grails-app** ?

```
Missing artifact org.grails:grails-dependencies:jar:2.3.7
```

Where is this dependency located?

*Appreciate your help!*

Comment: Can you add pom.xml to question?

Comment: This is a proxy issue
Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22618817/error-creating-a-new-grails-project-ggts-sts-eclipse-with-ggts-plugin